# Caml accent-sensitive

Tags: development, search, caml-query

I wonder if the caml supports accent-sensitive, I'm doing a query and have many records with an accent and realized that these items are not appearing
What can I do in this case?
I can use any search engine to filter the items in a custom list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CAML query do support diacritics / accents but you need to wrap the values in CDATA

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'><![CDATA[françois]]></Value></Eq></Where>
```

Watch out for your SQL Server collation (Should be Case insensitive, Accent, Kana & Width sensitive) too.

Comment: thanks for the comment.
However a doubt, if I search for "francois" should bring the results with the text "françois"
Except that it is not working

Comment: Unfortunately not, because "c" and "ç" are encoded differently in your database. If you used the collation "Accent insensitive" you would have the expected result.

Comment: I understood then in this case, I'd better use a search engine sharepoint, so I can filter the data?